# modify number from cell reference in QUERY function (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Is it possible to modify a number from a cell reference within the syntax of a QUERY function in Google Sheets without a helper cell/column?

If I have "5" in a cell, can I reference that cell and somehow subtract 1 when using the LIMIT option in the QUERY syntax so it returns four results?

I am including a sample sheet below as well as working and nonworking formulas.

link to sheet & cell
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lyCK5eIEQYjGFOxh5T_4BxeuDS-1zvMLq80IYn0dc38/edit#gid=1018697126&range=B1

working formula:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(currentTable),"limit "&B1&"",1)
```

nonworking attempt:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(currentTable),"limit "&B1&"-1",1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just subtract 1 from `B1` instead before passing it into the `query`.

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(currentTable),"limit "&B1-1,1)
```

#### Output:

[image: output]